# Is there a better way to do case insensitive queries?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph

I'm looking for a way to match claims values in a case insensitive way.

For instance, Wikidata has the following statement:

```
wd:Q1524522 wdt:P2002 'bouletcorp'
```

but, following the [case used in twitter](https://twitter.com/Bouletcorp), let's say that I would use the value `Bouletcorp` instead, which would give the following query, and fail to find any matching entity:

```sql
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P2002 "Bouletcorp" .
}
```

([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2002%20%22bouletcorp%22%20.%0A%7D))

A solution could be to use a Regex with an insensitive case flag as follow:

```sql
SELECT ?item WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P2002 ?twittername .
  FILTER (regex(?twittername, "Bouletcorp", "i"))
}
```

([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP2002%20%3Ftwittername%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28regex%28%3Ftwittername%2C%20%22Bouletcorp%22%2C%20%22i%22%29%29%0A%7D))

but how much less efficient would this query be? Isn't there a better way? As I understand it, this query would make the SPARQL engine pass all triples having a value for the requested property through a regex, which does sound inefficient. It's not that slow yet for [P2002](https://wikidata.org/entity/P2002), but I guess some properties having more than a million matching claims could be problematic, no?

Comment: There is nothing "better" in the SPARQL standard. Of course REGEX will use a scan + applying the regex over all values which can be slow. Depending on the triple store, there might be some built-ins resp. extension for fulltext search. As far as I know, Wikidata is hosted in a Blazegraph triple store, thus,you might have a look at the documentation.

Comment: It doesn't avoid the "touch every triple" case, but you could do a `?s ?p ?v filter (lcase(?v) = 'the string')`, which wouldn't require a whole regular expression comparison to be introduced. Plus, you wouldn't have to worry about whether the string you're looking for happens to contain regular expression sensitive characters.